# get prev input element by jquery

Tags: jquery, traversal

my code

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    <td>Other text 5</td>
    <td><input name="name5" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="records"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 7</td>
    <td>Other text 7</td>
    <td><input name="name7" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="records"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 13</td>
    <td>Other text 13</td>
    <td><input name="name13" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="13" name="records"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

get the middle input checkbox with

```
$('#mytable input[type=checkbox][name=records][value=7]')
```

good :-)

now, how can i get the prev input () and the next () input?

i try

```
$('#mytable input[type=checkbox][name=records][value=2]').prev('input[type=checkbox]')
```

for prev, but not works :-(

thanks :-)

Comment: Look at http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Comment: `$(theOneYouHave).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]');`

Comment: thanks adeneo, work great :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference to that middle checkbox in `checkbox`, and also assuming that there is only going to be one checkbox descendant of each `tr` element:

```
//Previous checkbox:
checkbox.closest("tr").prev().find(":checkbox");

//Next checkbox:
checkbox.closest("tr").next().find(":checkbox");
```

This gets the ancestor `tr` element with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), and then uses [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the previous or following `tr`, and then finds any checkbox descendants of that.

Also note the use of the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector, which is basically a shortcut to the attribute selector you are currently using. You can use either, but the attribute selector is probably a bit faster since it's a native CSS selector.